# how to delete firebase position value using swipe controller

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how to delete firebase values using position (swipe controller)
[image: My database picture]

if i delete values using below method,its delete random values,,i want delete selected value only

```
swipeController = new SwipeController(new SwipeControllerActions() {
        @Override
        public void onRightClicked(int position) {

            firebaseRecyclerAdapter1.notifyItemRemoved(position);
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("OrderItemsList").child(gg);
            mDataRef.child(d).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Removed  Item", FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.ERROR, R.drawable.ic_clear_black_24dp).show();
                        firebaseRecyclerAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        firebaseRecyclerAdapter1.startListening();


                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is the value of `gg`?

Comment: 2 example (Table no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using an adapter from FirebaseUI. In that case, you can get the `DatabaseReference` for the node at `position` with:

```
mDataRef = firebaseRecyclerAdapter1.getRef(position);
```

And then you can delete the data at that reference with:

```
mDataRef.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifiy which item you're trying to delete. For example, in your case, it should be:

```
mDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("OrderItemsList");
mDataRef.child("Egg Rice").removeValue().addOnCompleteListener.. // and the rest..
```

Here is how it should be without code: `OrderItemsList -> Egg Rice` child.

Comment: i define d string value recyclerview value

Comment: i need position using delete